# 'FirebaseAuth' is not assignable to type 'Auth'

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

After update my project dependencies, I have this error:

> ERROR in src/app/services/auth/auth.service.ts(19,5): error TS2322:
>   Type 'FirebaseAuth' is not assignable to type 'Auth'.   Types of
>   property 'app' are incompatible.
>       Type 'FirebaseApp' is not assignable to type 'App'.
>         Property 'messaging' is missing in type 'FirebaseApp'.

Screenshoot of the error
[image]

I have this code at line 19,5:

```
this.auth = angularFireAuth.auth;
```

Screenshoot of the code
[image]

My dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.6",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.6",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.6",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.6",
    "@firebase/app": "^0.1.10",
    "angular-file-saver": "^1.1.3",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.6",
    "codemirror": "^5.35.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.3",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "firebase": "^4.10.1",
    "firebase-auth": "^0.1.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "install": "^0.10.4",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.2",
    "ngx-editor": "^3.3.0-rc.9",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "survey-angular": "^1.0.10",
    "xlsx": "^0.11.19",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.20"
  },
```

What can it be?
Thank you!

Comment: Please don't show pictures of code and errors.  Copy your code into code blocks into the question so it's more easily readable and searchable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be an issue with the version you're using - there were breaking changes.

`constructor(af: AngularFire) {
  af.database.list('foo');
  af.auth;
}`

Should now be:

`constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase, afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
  db.list('foo');
  afAuth.authState;
}`

Please see: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-4-upgrade.md

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to tell, but you are trying to assign something in a wrong way.
Please check environment file or file where you have defined firebase.auth.Auth. Sorry, but not enough code to debug.